# ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 breaks projects

Tags: asp.net-core

If I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 to create a new ASP.NET Core MVC app, it runs just fine. However, if I take said app and update it's Nuget packages to ASP.NET Core 1.0.1, I get the following build errors:

```
Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible cause
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.
```

Is this a bug, or something environmental?

**Addendum:**

The log from the restore looks fine:

```
log  : Restoring packages for <path to project>\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in E:\Software Projects\subq\src\SubQ.API\project.json...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: <path to project>\project.lock.json
log  : <path to project>\project.json
log  : Restore completed in 6210ms.
```

project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1"
    },

    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": [
                "dotnet5.6",
                "portable-net45+win8"
            ],
            "runtimes": {
                "win10-x64": {}
            }
        }
    },

    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },

    "runtimeOptions": {
        "configProperties": {
            "System.GC.Server": true
        }
    },

    "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
            "wwwroot",
            "Views",
            "Areas/**/Views",
            "appsettings.json",
            "web.config"
        ]
    },

    "scripts": {
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    }
}
```

The latest SDK is installed.

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core 1.0.1 SDK?

Comment: Also, try running `dotnet restore` command in the folder where your project.json is.

Comment: @Tseng: Yes I already have it installed.

Comment: @Ignas: Yes. Visual Studio runs a restore during build, and I've run it manually from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `runtimes` should be placed outside of the `frameworks` setting. Change

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ],
        "runtimes": {
            "win10-x64": {}
        }
    }
},
```

to

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
    }
},  
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win81-x64": {}
},
```

I also had to add `win81-x64`, since I am running on Windows 8.1, and compiler was complaining about it.

Let me know if this worked!

Comment: Ok. That's the right schema. I've seen some references to the runtimes objects, but never in the context of the whole file. The one time I did see it, it was embedded under frameworks. Maybe that applied to an earlier version. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @kettch: Consult http://schemastore.org/json/ for available schemas. Project.json as well as other json based configurations are listed there with it's schema. Most recent project.json is located here: http://json.schemastore.org/project

Comment: @Tseng Cool resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/267:
When updating using nuget the "type":"platform" is removed, which effectively changes the project to stand-alone and thus would force the requirement of a runtimes section.

For me manually adding the "type" : "platform" to the project.json file resolved the issue.

```
    "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "platform"
        },
```

And also acoording https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/267:
Updating through the NuGet UI calls into the project system to update project.json, "type": "platform" is dropped during that edit. NuGet 3.5.0 RTM (not released yet) will have a workaround for this issue.